# правописание слова

Tags: орфография

Слово ***экспортно-образующий*** пишется через дефис, слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Может, зкпортообразующий? Без Н?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это в значении "*образовывать экспорт*", то **слитно** и обязательно **без -н-**: это суффикс прилагательного или наречия, а здесь первая из основ слова - существительное. Иначе будет странность вроде "*импортНозамещения*" или "*конкурентНоспособности*". Соответственно: "**экспортоообразующий**" - вряд ли здесь желаемый смысл - "образовывать (что-то другое) экспортно" (от наречия).

Но в близком по структуре понятии, составленном из "**экспорт**" и "**ориентированный**", возможны разные варианты словообразования в рамках одного и того же смысла: через прилагательное/наречие (*с экспортной ориентацией = ориентированный экспортно*) или от существительного (*ориентированный на экспорт*). В первом случае (есть **-н-**) словари синонимов дают раздельное (от *наречия*) или дефисное (от *прилагательного*) написание, а во втором (**без -н-**; таков и наш случай - от *существительного*) - написание слитное:

> *экспорт**н**о ориентированный* (ориентированный экспортно)
>
> *экспорт**н**о-ориентированный* (с экспортной ориентацией)
>
> *экспортоориентированный* (ориентированный на экспорт; ср.: *экспортообразующий*)

Comment: @ Alex_ander,а в чем смысловая разница между раздельным и дефисным и слитным написанием?

Comment: Смысловой разницы нет в случае примера с "-ориентированный", есть различие в этимологии (от какой части речи первая основа). Но в случае с "-образующий" смысл имеет только вариант, образованный от существительного (образовывать что?), он без -н-, а при этом словари фиксируют только слитное написание; могу только предположить, что для дефисного написания и вторая основа (при первой от существительного) должна (в тенденции) иметь смысл существительного, а не причастия/глагола ("наряд-заказ", экспорт-импорт" и т. п.), хотя в схеме из двух существительных это не единственно возможный способ.

Comment: Теперь ясно,спасибо!